# enabling CORS in .net core webAPI

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, cors

I've installed NuGet package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors 2.2.0
then in my .net core webAPI Startup.cs I have done the following:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) { 
......
services.AddCors();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }

    app.UseCors(options =>
    options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:52556")
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader());

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Then when I send post request from my angular app in console I see this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:52556/api/PaymentDetail'
>   from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I thought I've enabled CORS but it seems that something is blocking it. What can be done to solve this problem ?

Comment: You're doing it the wrong way around. Whatever's running at `localhost:52556` doesn't approve of the origin `localhost:4200`. I don't know which of those is where you've put the code you're showing but it's got the wrong origin.

Comment: Remove options.WithOrigins or add localhost:4200 instead and this would work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting Origin for you asp host.

Just replace this line

```
options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:52556")
```

with

```
options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way. Ithink it's because you are allowing URLs with "http://localhost:52556" only. Using "*" will enable all URLs and if you can want you can limit it to any specific one.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
  .........................
    services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("NoRestrictions",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            });;
     ...............
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, IOptions<AppServerSettings> appServerSettings)
{
    ..........
    app.UseCors("NoRestrictions");
    ..........
}
```

Comment: `AllowSpecificOrigin` should be renamed to  `NoRestrictions` keeping in view your code out there

Comment: @manish I added that as he can change it to any specific URL if he wants. Well thanks for the suggestion. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved same problem in C# by annotations/attributes,

```
[System.Web.Http.Cors.EnableCors(origins: "http://localhost:4200", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class StudentsController : ApiController{}
```

in MVC,
use,

```
// For Action, 
[HttpGet]
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get(){}
// For Controller,   
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[EnableCors("AllowSpecificOrigin")]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase{}
```

in your case, replace with this If specific to port number process `4200`,

```
options.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200");
```

or you can put `No Restrictions`,

```
app.UseCors("NoRestrictions");// To config
// To service
services.AddCors(options =>
{
  options.AddPolicy("NoRestrictions",
         builder => builder.WithOrigins("*").AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
});
```

Checks whats the origin,
1) checks port number `(e.g. 8080 or 8888)`
2) domain and sub domain `(e.g. google.com or google.net)`
3) schema `(e.g. http or https)`

register origin,

go inside `Startup.ConfigureServices` and call `services.AddCors();`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddCors();
}
```

enable cors now,
go `Startup.Configure` and call `app.UseCors(builder =>
       builder.WithOrigins("http://google.com"));`